# Apply numpy.where on condition with either list or numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I discovered that `numpy.where` behaves differently when applied on a condition such as `foo==2` when `foo` is a list or `foo` is a `numpy.array`

```
foo = ["a","b","c"]
bar = numpy.array(["a","b","c"])
numpy.where(foo == "a") # Returns array([])
numpy.where(bar == "a") # Returns array([0])
```

I want the same command to make this applicable to either list or numpy.array, and I am concerned about how to perform this efficiently. Is the following ok ?

```
numpy.where(numpy.array(foo, copy=False) == "a") # Returns array([0])
numpy.where(numpy.array(bar, copy=False) == "a") # Returns array([0])
```

Result is as expected, but is this the best way to answer my need ? Using each time `numpy.array` constructor is the best way to ensure object type ?

Thanks !

Comment: Note that your problem comes from `foo == "a"` and `bar == "a"` and not `np.where`. **Lists do not behave like numpy arrays**. Expecting anything but `False` from `["a","b"]  == "b"` is as absurd as expecting `list() == str()` to give an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really looking for the most `numpy`-esque solution, use [`np.asarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
numpy.where(numpy.asarray(foo) == "a")
```

And if you also want your code to work with subclasses of `numpy.ndarray`, without "downconverting" them to their base class of `ndarray`, then use [`np.asanyarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html#numpy.asanyarray):

```
numpy.where(numpy.asanyarray(foo) == "a")
```

This works for `np.matrix` for instance, without converting it to an array. I suppose that this would also ensure that the `np.matrix` instance doesn't get copied or reconstructed into an array prior to checking.

**Note:** I think that copies are made by `np.array` for lists, because it needs to construct the array object. This can be seen in the [documentation for `np.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html):

```
copy : bool, optional
    If true (default), then the object is copied.
    Otherwise, a copy will only be made if __array__ returns a copy, if
    obj is a nested sequence, or if a copy is needed to satisfy any of the
    other requirements (dtype, order, etc.).
```

`np.asarray` would also make a copy in this case.

Comment: numpy.asanyarray is preferred and working. Thanks for highlighting numpy.array constructor may copy object even if copy=False is provided !

Answer (score 2):

To me your solution is already the best:

```
numpy.where(numpy.array(foo, copy=False) == "a")
```

It is concise, very clear and totaly efficient thanks to `copy=False`.